# TIdTCPClient response first bytes are lost

Tags: delphi, indy

I made a program in Delphi XE4 using Indy TCPClient component to send some binary data over a custom port to ESP8266 module and read the response that is binary bytes. The problem is that first bytes of response are lost. (usually 2 bytes get lost). The ESP8266 program has no problem. Here is my Delphi code:

```
var
  b: array [0..2060] of Byte;
  k: Integer;
  s: String;
begin
...
s := '';
if (not TcpCl.Connected) then TcpCl.Connect;
if (TcpCl.Connected) then
  begin
  TcpCl.IOHandler.RecvBufferSize := 100;
  for k := 0 to z - 1 do
    TcpCl.IOHandler.Write(b[k]);
  s := '';
  for k := 0 to 12 do
    s := s + IntToHex(TcpCl.IOHandler.ReadByte, 2);
  DataMem.Text := s;
  TcpCl.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is nothing in this code that would cause Indy to lose bytes, so they have to be getting lost on the network before Indy receives them.  Unless you are misusing `TIdTCPClient`, such as by having another thread read from it (and that includes calling the `Connected()` method, which performs a read operation internally) at the same time this code is running.

Comment: The code is running in main program and not a thread. I used connected method before sending request.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `Connected()` after `Connect()`.  `Connect()` raises an exception if it cannot connect to the server, and `Write()` and `ReadByte()` will raise exceptions if the connection is lost. What you are missing is a `try/finally` between `Connect()` and `Disconnect()`, though, in case an exception really is raised by `Write()` or `ReadByte()`.  BTW, calling `ReadByte()` in a loop is not very efficient, you should use `ReadBytes()` instead to read all 13 bytes to a `TIdBytes` in one go, then loop through that byte array to build your `string`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.